Delve hangs at "DAP server listening at:". on Windows 11 ARM64 VM
I am trying to debug some go code on my windows 11 arm64 VM running on my mac. It has been 3 days that I am trying to fix this and I don't know why it keeps getting stuck at "DAP server listening at:  127.0.0.1:51204".
Here are some details about the versions I am using and things I've tried: I am using go 1.23 amd64 edition as it turns out that delve doesn't support arm64 yet. I am trying to run with debug on vs code arm64 1.92.2 but it gets stuck there. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling go as well as dlv. I tried running delve through the command line as other suggested and I faced the same problem. The code runs fine without debug so I don't think that's the problem. I tried using different launch profiles like:
{

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch file",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${file}"
        },

        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "trace": "verbose",
            "showLog": true,
            "logOutput": "rpc"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "env": {},
            "args": [],
            "trace": "log",
            "dlvFlags": ["--check-go-version=false"]
        }
    ]
}

No log traces show up even with verbose and sometimes I don't even get the debug bar on top left. It just keeps showing that it's loading. I tried leaving it for a few hours in hopes of it getting unstuck but it just gets stuck there. I tried a lot of other small things (e.g. running vs with administrator, checking if local ports are blocked on firewall) and looked all over the net but still no solution. What could this be? Has anyone faced the same issue? I need to debug some functionality that only work on windows so figuring this out is essential for me.
